# Converters behavior in NumPy loadtxt not understood

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to read in data from a text file using numpy.loadtxt with the converters argument. I have a mixture of columns of ints and strings. The code is:

```
a, b, c, d, e = np.loadtxt(infile, delimiter = ',', usecols=(0, 2, 5, 8, 9), skiprows = 1,
                           unpack = True, converters = dict(zip((0, 2, 5, 8, 9), (int, float, float, int, int))))
```

The data are read in correctly and unpacked correctly, but all the variables (a, b, c, d, and e) end up as floats. Am I making a mistake in the converters syntax?

**Edit trying answer**

I tried using dtype = (int,float,float,int,int) as suggested by @joris as:

```
a,b,c,d,e = np.loadtxt(infile,delimiter = ',', usecols=(0,2,5,8,9), skiprows = 1, unpack = True, dtype = (int,float,float,int,int))
```

But I get the following error:

```
     41                                            skiprows = 1,
     42                                            unpack = True,
---> 43                                            dtype = (int,float,float,int,int))
     44
     45

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.pyc in loadtxt(fname, dtype, comments, delimiter, converters, skiprows, usecols, unpack)
    665     try:
    666         # Make sure we're dealing with a proper dtype

--> 667         dtype = np.dtype(dtype)
    668         defconv = _getconv(dtype)
    669

TypeError: data type not understood
WARNING: Failure executing file: <forward_NDMMF.py>
```

I am using NumPy v. 1.5.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For specifying the type of the different columns, you can use the argument `dtype` instead of `converters`:

```
dtype=(int,float,float,int,int)
```

**EDIT:**

Apparantly, this type of `dtype` specification does not seem to work with `loadtxt`, but it works with `genfromtxt` (*Does anybody know why this does not work work with `loadtxt`, or is this one of the extra capabilities of `genfromtxt`?*)

If you want to use `loadtxt`, a structured dtype specification with tuples works, like `[('f0', int), ('f1', float)]` instead of `(int, float)`

But there is another problem. When working with such structured dtypes, and so structured arrays (different types for different columns), the `unpack` does not seem to work. At least with a simple example I tried. But that could be a bug that is already solved: http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/ticket/1458 (but for that, you have to upgrade to even 1.6).

Comment: @joris, it seems like `dtype` won't accept a plain tuple of types like that. You need a record `dtype`.

Comment: @senderle, strange, I didn't test it, but copied it straight from the numpy user manual, so I assumed it was correct

Comment: @senderle: with a simple example it work with a plain tuple (numpy 1.5.1)

Comment: @mishaF, maybe try ``genfromtxt`` instead of ``loadtxt`` (with just the same arguments). I tried it with a simple example with ``genfromtxt``, and then the ``dtype`` works (only the unpack gives a problem then).

Comment: @joris. Thanks for the update. The unpack behavior is important because without it I could do type conversion while parsing the array after reading. I will try genfromtxt.

Answer (score 4):

The `loadtxt` documentation indicates that
`converters` should contain functions that [*specifically return floats*](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.5.x/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html):

> **converters** : dict, optional
>
> > A dictionary mapping column number to a function that will convert that column to a float. E.g., if column 0 is a date string: converters = {0: datestr2num}. Converters can also be used to provide a default value for missing data: converters = {3: lambda s: float(s or 0)}. Default: None.

If you want integers instead, you'll need to cast the floats using the `dtype` keyword.

```
>>> numpy.loadtxt('th.txt', delimiter=',', usecols=(0, 2, 3), converters=dict(zip((0, 2, 3), (float, float, float))), dtype=([('i1', '<i4'), ('i2', '<f4'), ('i3', '<i4')]))
array([(1, 3.2000000476837158, 4), (1, 3.2000000476837158, 4),
       (1, 3.2000000476837158, 4), (1, 3.2000000476837158, 4),
       (1, 3.2000000476837158, 4), (1, 3.2000000476837158, 4),
       (1, 3.2000000476837158, 4), (1, 3.2000000476837158, 4),
       (1, 3.2000000476837158, 4)],
      dtype=[('i1', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('i2', '<i4')])
```

Of course, you don't actually need `converters` in this case -- that's really for converting arbitrary string values like `'True'` to numeric values. Furthermore, if you actually want a simple two-dimensional array instead of a record array, then don't pass a record format:

```
>>> numpy.loadtxt('th.txt', delimiter=',', usecols=(0, 2, 3), dtype=int)
array([[1, 3, 4],
       [1, 3, 4],
       [1, 3, 4],
       [1, 3, 4],
       [1, 3, 4],
       [1, 3, 4],
       [1, 3, 4],
       [1, 3, 4],
       [1, 3, 4]])
```

But if you do this you can't specify format by column.

Comment: Acutally, just passing a tuple of types ([joris's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416688/converters-behavior-in-numpy-loadtxt-not-understood/6416838#6416838)) works for numpy 1.5.1.

Comment: I should have read the docs more closely! Specifying format by column is my ultimate goal here though.